# Which books did John read which books? Displacement and reconstruction

Tags: english, reconstruction

In his talk available on YouTube as [“Language, Creativity, and the Limits of Understanding” by Professor Noam Chomsky (4-21-16)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=XNSxj0TVeJs&t=56m36s) at 56:36s Noam Chomsky starts talking about the phenomenon of *displacement*.

While I believe I understand what *displacement*, *reconstruction*, and *deletion of copies* mean I cannot reconcile it with the example given: "Which books did John read?"

Prof. Chomsky says that the sentence is interpreted something like "For which books X John read books X" and later "Which books did John read which books?".

Could you explain this to my simple mind?